# SQL - SELECT statement over two tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to create a SELECT statement which selects two different columns from two tables in the same database.

```
SELECT  TNC301X.DIRIN, NC301B.PATH301
FROM    TNC301X, NC301B
WHERE   TNC301X.EDIPROC like 'P30_' AND NC301B.EDIPROC like 'P30_'
    AND (LASTENRIN > 0) OR (LF301M > 0) 
    AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%saptemp%')
    AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%SAPTEMP%')  
    AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
    AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%Windows%');
```

I just want to select the content in the columns DIRIN and PATH301.

```
TNC301X.DIRIN         NC301B.PATH301
\\ABC\DEF\            \\ABC\DEF\
\\GHI\JKL\            \\GHI\JKL\ 
\\MNO\PQR\            \\MNO\PQR\
```

The statement seems to be syntactically correct but the output 
is not. When i create a single statement for each table the output is correct. The tables are not equal.

**SELECT-PATH301**

```
SELECT  PATH301 
FROM    NC301B
WHERE   EDIPROC like 'P30_'
    AND (LF301M > 0) 
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%saptemp%')
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%SAPTEMP%')  
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
    AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%Windows%');
```

**SELECT-DIRIN**

```
SELECT  DIRIN
FROM    TNC301X
WHERE   EDIPROC like 'P30_'
    AND (LASTENRIN > 0) 
    AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%saptemp%')
    AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%SAPTEMP%')  
    AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
    AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%Windows%');
```

All I want to do is to combine these statements but I don't know how.

EDIT: I got it.

FYI

```
SELECT DIRIN 
FROM TNC301X 
WHERE EDIPROC like 'P30_' 
AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%saptemp%') 
AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%SAPTEMP%')
AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%Windows%')
UNION ALL 
SELECT PATH301 
FROM NC301B 
WHERE EDIPROC like 'P30_' 
AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%saptemp%') 
AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%SAPTEMP%')
AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%Windows%');
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp check this out there is alot of help to find and some nice examples. I think JOIN is the one you look for

Comment: Sorry :) im using oracle only.

Answer (score 2):

To Join two table you need to match id of two table like 'where table1.id = table2.id'. In this case I think id to join these two table is EDIPROC column. I may be wrong.

```
SELECT NC.PATH301,TNC.DIRIN
FROM (
      SELECT  PATH301 
      FROM    NC301B
      WHERE   EDIPROC like 'P30_'
      AND (LF301M > 0) 
      AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%saptemp%')
      AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%SAPTEMP%')  
      AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
      AND (PATH301 NOT LIKE '%Windows%')
 ) NC, 
 (   
      SELECT  DIRIN
      FROM    TNC301X
      WHERE   EDIPROC like 'P30_'
      AND (LASTENRIN > 0) 
      AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%saptemp%')
      AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%SAPTEMP%')  
      AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%usr%')  
      AND (DIRIN NOT LIKE '%Windows%')
 ) TNC
 WHERE NC.EDIPROC  = TNC.EDIPROC
```

Comment: This SELECT Statement is not working for me.

) AS NC;

seems to be not supported in oracle. 

Error at line 11:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

Comment: Sorry I forget to remove ; near NC

Comment: Oracle doesn't support `AS` for a table alias. You need to remove the `AS` for the derived tables.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for your guide. I am not familiar with oracle

Answer (score 0):

`Union` is what you are looking for. Just combine your two `Select` statements.
If you expect to find duplicate results in your tables and you want all of them to appear in your output, use `Union all`
[More info on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: How about setting out an example specific to the OP questions rather than pointing them to another website that isn't the official documentation. Also, you have failed highlight that the OP is using old, and superseded, syntax for joins that doesn't meet current ISO standards.